# Simple parallel example with channel, leading to deadlock

Tags: go, deadlock

I'm trying to implement a simple parallelization example in golang using channels. The code tries to implement a parallelized map function. Made channels buffered too for easing constraints on blocking nature of channel. but code still leads to a deadlock.

```
func pmmap(inp []int, f func(int) int, p int) {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var output []chan int
    tot := len(inp)
    out := make(chan int, tot)
    slice := tot / p

    for i := 0; i < p; i++ {
        temp := make(chan int, slice)
        output = append(output, temp)
        start_ind := slice * i
        end_ind := start_ind + slice
        fmt.Println(start_ind, end_ind)

        wg.Add(1)
        go func(si, ei int, out chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
            fmt.Println("goroutine started with ", si, ei)
            for ind := si; ind < ei; ind++ {
                out <- f(inp[ind])
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(start_ind, end_ind, output[i], &wg)
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for i := 0; i < p; i++ {
            for val := range output[i] {
                out <- val
            }
            close(output[i])
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(&wg)

    wg.Add(1)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for i := range out {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(&wg)

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 6)
    wg.Wait()
    close(out)
}

func add4(i int) int {
    return i + 4
}

func main() {
    temp := []int{}
    for i := 1; i <= 20; i++ {
        temp = append(temp, i)
    }
    pmmap(temp, add4, 2)
}
```

from the output of above code, I get the deadlock is because channel output[1] is never read. but I'm not sure why

```
0 10
10 20
goroutine started with  0 10
goroutine started with  10 20
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `range` over a channel keeps trying to receive from the channel until the channel is closed, but you didn't `close` channels after finished sending.

Add `close(out)` before `wg.Done` in your code will fix it.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/NbKTx6Lke7X

Edit: fixed a bug of closing closed channel.